# import js file to header all jsp in liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm going to import a js file to the header of all pages exist in liferay portal.
I know I have to do in Hook.I put import this js into init.jsp in ..\html\common , but  was import to all elements of the liferay pages.
I don't know where put this file?

Comment: http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/jQuery+in+liferay+6.1.20+and+6.2?_36_pageResourcePrimKey=32598825

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do this in a hook. Do it in your theme as the theme is responsible for generating the whole document, including the `<html>` and `<head>` sections.

In the theme, override `templates/portal_normal.vm`. It should be obvious where to put the script reference.

You'll override this file by creating a `docroot/_diffs/templates` folder and copy `docroot/templates/portal_normal.vm` to that location. Then edit the file in `docroot/_diffs/templates`, build and deploy your theme.